# Get number value from HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I get a number value from inside the HTML element, which I would later use in the countdown? I keep getting error that document.getElementById(...) is null, am I missing something with concatenation? Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6ddLc0L/

```
<h1 id="num">50</h1>

<div id="status"></div>

<button onclick='countDown(secs, "status")'>Start countdown</button>
<button onclick='increaseNumber()'>Increase</button>


var num = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;
var secs = num.parseInt();

function increaseNumber() {
    secs++;
}

function countDown(secs, elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem); //(elem)
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
    //if timer goes into negative numbers
    if(secs < 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown complete!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
    }

    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+', "'+elem+'")',1000);
}
```

Comment: `parseInt()` is a function, not a method, i.e. you need `parseInt(str)`, not `str.parseInt()`. Also, your Fiddle will fail as you're using inline, DOM-zero events via attributes (onclick) etc. Since JS Fiddle code gets closured, these won't find the functions they call. Use proper event registration instead.

Comment: The code in your question fails to show how you loaded the JS. There are no script tags. The code in the JS Fiddle gives a completely different set of error messages to the ones you described in the question. You need to provide a **real** [MCVE] before we can tell what your *actual* problem is.

Comment: The typical reason for `document.getElementById()` not finding an element is that you run the JavaScript code inside `<head>` as soon as it loads, before the rest of the HTML (and the element in question) has finished loading. Of course, the code you've shared does not exhibit this problem.

Comment: ^^ ... But the linked fiddle exhibits the problem. Change "Load type" in Javascript settings to "No wrap - in <body>", fix the `parseInt` issue, and your code should [work](https://jsfiddle.net/L6ddLc0L/). This option places all the script just before the closing `body` tag, that way `#num` exists before the script will be run. Notice also, that you need `return` statement at the end of the `if` block to prevent the timer running. `clearTimeout` in this case is actually useless.

Comment: Also some browsers will think  a button without type="button" is a submit button and reload the page

Comment: Using "in head" https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/esa84kmu/

Comment: @mplungjan The button should be within a form in that case.

Comment: @Teemu - no. A button may submit the url the button is on in older IEs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `parseInt`-method to a `function` that it actually is and fixed the bad `setTimeout` parameter. As the others mention, you should note that Javascript gets executed as it gets interpreted by the browser. Therefore if you include a `<script>`-tag in your `<head>` that will access fields of the body it won't find them as they're not yet interpreted by the browser.

```js
var num = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;
var secs = parseInt(num);

function increaseNumber() {
  secs++;
}

function countDown(secs, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem); //(elem)
  element.innerHTML = "Please wait for " + secs + " seconds";
  //if timer goes into negative numbers
  if (secs < 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown complete!</h2>';
    element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
  }

  secs--;
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    countDown(secs, elem);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="num">50</h1>

<div id="status"></div>

<button onclick='countDown(secs, "status")'>Start countdown</button>
<button onclick='increaseNumber()'>Increase</button>
```

Comment: `var num = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;` must be executed after the element has rendered

Answer (score 2):

You badly use parseInt(). You must call it this way.

```
var secs = parseInt(num,10);
```

also take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp) how your code in html should looks

Comment: True. But he says that *document.getElementById(...) is null* so he's having some other issues before.